# Resolving digest overflow issue on AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to output a random number in my view but keep getting the following message:

`Error: [$rootScope:infdig] 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!`

It appears to be a digest outflow issue, but I am not sure how to resolve it? This is my code so far:

**HTML**

```
<p>{{getRandomNumber(2, 12)}} providers nearby</p>
```

**controller.js**

```
.controller('ServicesCtrl', function($scope, ServicesData, $stateParams) {  
  $scope.getRandomNumber = function(min, max){
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min) + min);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The curly braces `{{ }}` create a $watch. Angular will $watch the expression and keep trying (up to a max of 10 times) until it gets a stable value. Since you're returning a random number, it will never be stable.

Here's a workaround. Assign the random result to a variable using `ngInit` and use that stabilized value in your expression.

```
<p ng-init="foo=getRandomNumber()">{{foo}} providers nearby</p>
```

Judging by the "providers nearby" text, I think the issues you're encountering won't be a problem with your final code and you won't need that workaround (because it's unlikely you'll have a different number of providers in the middle of a $digest cycle).